# Notify users of new release with IAP

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on an iOS app containing in-app purchases. From time to time, we'll release new IAPs for users to buy. To do that, we'll need to release new versions of the app, e.g. we'll release v1.0.4 containing new IAPs. We plan to offer users a way to receive push notifications, telling them when new IAP products are available.

My problem is: how can I send the notification so that users can tap on the notification and immediately purchase the product?

If we send the notification the very instant that v1.0.4 is released, users won't be able to tap on the notification and buy the product, because they can't possibly have downloaded v1.0.4 yet. We could delay the notification for a day or two, but some users/devices will necessarily straggle behind regardless.

We could send a push notification redirecting users to the App Store to update the app. But we wanted users to tap the notification and immediately see the Buy screen for our new IAP. Making users tap on a notification, then tap Update, then wait for the download, then re-open the app, and *then* buy the IAP is a lot of hassle for our users.

How do other developers handle this problem?

Comment: I would implement the notification tap handling so that if the IAP product is recognised by the current version then you start the purchase process. If it isn't recognised then you advise the user to upgrade. Combine this with a delay between new version and notification perhaps combined with analytics that tell you what version your users are running so you can delay until a reasonable % have upgraded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to allow the old version of your app to download the content of the new IAP without upgrading to a new binary version.

Apple allows you to submit IAPs that are not associated with a binary; just fill in the metadata, upload a screenshot, and tap "Submit for Review." In that case, Apple just reviews the metadata, because they can't review the IAP's content.

Once that's approved, the old v1.0.3 app can receive a push notification that the new content is available. When the user taps the notification, the app can refresh its list of in-app purchases (e.g. by making a web request to your web site), download the new content, and make it available to users without a new v1.0.4 release.

You might want to submit a new release anyway, to include the content in the app bundle, and so as to present release notes to users in the list of updated apps in the App Store.